# decorators: "this" is undefined when accessed in descriptor.value

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I am trying out decorators, I have written a decorator that basically returns a new function that does some `console.log.

This is what my decorator looks like:

```
function test(target, name, descriptor) {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    console.log("bbau");
    if (typeof original === 'function') {
        descriptor.value = function (...args) {
            console.log(`Arguments: ${args}`);
            try {
                console.log("executing");
                const result = original.apply(this, args);
                console.log("done");
                console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
                return result;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    return descriptor;
}
```

And this is how I am using it:

```
class TestController extends BaseController<//..> {
    // ... 
    @test
    testIt(req: Request, res: Response) : Response {
       this.sendResponse();
    }

    sendResponse(options: ISendResponseOptions, res: Response) : Response {
       // return response
    }
}
```

``
However, when executed an error is raised: `Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendResponse' of undefined`.

Any thoughts about what it could be? Thanks!

Comment: Use regular (pre-ES6) function expression syntax as pointed out by @DavinTryon

Comment: @DavinTryon  just updated the code, doesn't work

Comment: How do you call `testIt`?

Comment: @DavinTryon express: `router.route("/").post(testController.testIt);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally use an arrow function when you want to capture `this` from the context you declared the function in (or when `this` does not matter). In this case you really want `this` to be the object the function was called on so you should use a regular function :

```
const test = (target, name, descriptor) => {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    if (typeof original === 'function') {
          descriptor.value = function (...args) {
            console.log(`Arguments: ${args}`);
            try {
                console.log("executing");
                const result = original.apply(this, args);
                console.log("done");
                console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
                return result;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    return descriptor;
}
```

You can test it out in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20test%20%3D%20(target%2C%20name%2C%20descriptor)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20original%20%3D%20descriptor.value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20original%20%3D%3D%3D%20'function')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.value%20%3D%20function%20(...args)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60Arguments%3A%20%24%7Bargs%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22executing%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20original.apply(this%2C%20args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22done%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60Result%3A%20%24%7Bresult%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20catch%20(e)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60Error%3A%20%24%7Be%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20e%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20descriptor%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestController%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40test%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testIt()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22testit%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.sendResponse()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22r%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sendResponse()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22sendResponse%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20TestController().testIt())

If you use this function as a parameter to another function you should also call `bind` to set `this` for the function (otherwise the caller will determine the value of `this`):

```
router.route("/").post(testController.testIt.bind(testController))
```

Comment: @Sid I stand by the answer, the arrow function should not be used here. Maybe there is some other problem as well (how are you calling the functions). I added a playground link that demonstrates the decorator working

Comment: You are absolutely right about the arrow function, indeed I am trying to figure it out if there's another error somewhere

Comment: @Sid saw the comments, added a resolution for that

Comment: works with the `bind(testController` can you please take a few minutes to update the question why it works now?

Comment: @Sid added s short explanation.. does it make it clear why `bind` is necessary ?

Comment: Yes, thanks you very much! It all makes sense now :)